# Spring boot, runnable jar can't load package-info.class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar, package-info

We use Spring boot with hibernate database mapping.
The entities contains JSON columns mapped as a customized types defined using **package-info.java** file.

When we run the spring-project from Eclipse IDE everything is ok and we can call our web services.

When we generate an executable jar and we try to call our web services the following error is raised :

```
mai 04, 2017 1:35:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to execute job Test] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BOOT-INF/classes/com/test/package-info (wrong name: com/test/package-info)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

The file package-info.class is into the jar BOOT-INF/classes/com/test/package-info
What can be wrong ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's trying to load package info? It's using the wrong name

Comment: Its contains annotations for a user type definition used for hibernate JSON column mapping. The content was as : 
@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(name = "UserJsonType", typeClass = StringJsonUserType.class)
 
package com.bean;

import com.bean.type.StringJsonUserType; Actually we resolved the problem by replacing the definition of the type in all classes thus we delete the package-info.java. But is there a way to used it ?

Comment: I'm stuck in the same situation. I created a JAXB reader within a spring boot/spring batch application. Inside Eclipse everithing it's OK. When I build with Maven and then run it, I get  a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BOOT-INF/classes...`. Maybe the problem is the way the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` packages the compiled classes. I'm trying to investigate further...

Comment: Same problem, with spring-boot 1.5.x, this all worked fine previously. Can anyone at spring assist?

Comment: For anyone else in the spring world, here is a sample project re-producing the issue: https://github.com/nfedyk/spring-boot-jpa-issue-01

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by disabling package scan and autodetection of classed for Hibernate

```
<persistence-unit name="sqlProvider" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>     
    <class>com.example.package.dao</class>

    .........     
    <properties>
        <property name="exclude-unlisted-classes" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="hbm" />
        .........
    </properties>
    .........
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to disable scanning as manually adding all classes to `persistence.xml` wasn't an option. Since we do not actually use package level annotations for hibernate in our project, I created this little abomination:

```
package com.example;

import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.ScanResultImpl;
import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.StandardScanner;
import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ScanEnvironment;
import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ScanOptions;
import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ScanParameters;
import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ScanResult;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Collections;

public class HibernateHackScanner extends StandardScanner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateHackScanner.class);

    @Override
    public ScanResult scan(ScanEnvironment environment, ScanOptions options, ScanParameters parameters) {
        log.info("Hack-Scanner is active, annotated packages will not be found by this scanner.");
        ScanResult scan = super.scan(environment, options, parameters);
        return new ScanResultImpl(Collections.emptySet(), scan.getLocatedClasses(), scan.getLocatedMappingFiles());
    }
}
```

Then I enabled this custom scanner in `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.scanner" value="com.example.HibernateHackScanner"/>
```

This scanner uses the standard scanner under the hood and simply discards all annotated packages which have `boot_inf.classes` etc. prepended to their package. If you actually need package level annotations you would need to get a bit more sophisticated than this crutch, though. But this works for me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Nestor Fedyk solution helped me in resolving the issue.

please find the code below, i have added the solution to my hibernate config file

**"exclude-unlisted-classes"
"hibernate.archive.autodetection"** properties added

```
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="rcsDataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="corePersistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxx</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxx</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">250</prop>            
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">5</prop>            
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">300</prop>
            <prop key="exclude-unlisted-classes">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">"hbm"</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I use `cxf-codegen-plugin` to generate entites. In my case excluding `package-info` class solved the problem. I deleted `package-info.class` from project file, add extraargs to pom file like:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>

                <executions>
                          <execution>
                            <id>mvn s</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                                <wsdlOptions>
                                    <wsdlOption>
                                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/YOURWSDL.wsdl</wsdl>
                                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/YOURWSDL.wsdl</wsdlLocation>

                                        <bindingFiles>
                                            <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                                        </bindingFiles>

                                    </wsdlOption>

                                    <wsdlOption>
                                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/YOURWSDL.wsdl</wsdl>
                                        <!--<extraargs>-->
                                            <!--<extraarg>-impl</extraarg>-->
                                            <!--<extraarg>-server</extraarg>-->
                                        <!--</extraargs>&ndash;&gt;-->
                                    </wsdlOption>
                                </wsdlOptions>

                                <defaultOptions>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-xjc-npa</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </defaultOptions>

                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and package file: `mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage -DskipTests`. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with a modification of Jan Thomä's solution:

```
package com.example;

import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.PackageDescriptorImpl;
import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.ScanResultImpl;
import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.internal.StandardScanner;
import org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.*;
import org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveDescriptorFactory;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CustomHibernateScanner extends StandardScanner {

    private static final String SPRING_BOOT_JAR_PREFIX = "BOOT-INF.classes.";

    public CustomHibernateScanner() {
    }

    public CustomHibernateScanner(ArchiveDescriptorFactory value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public ScanResult scan(ScanEnvironment environment, ScanOptions options, ScanParameters parameters) {
        ScanResult result = super.scan(environment, options, parameters);
        Set<PackageDescriptor> pkgDesc = result.getLocatedPackages().stream()
                .map(this::fixPackageDescriptor)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return new ScanResultImpl(pkgDesc,
                result.getLocatedClasses(),
                result.getLocatedMappingFiles());
    }

    private PackageDescriptor fixPackageDescriptor(PackageDescriptor pd) {
        if (pd.getName().startsWith(SPRING_BOOT_JAR_PREFIX)) {
            return new PackageDescriptorImpl(pd.getName().substring(SPRING_BOOT_JAR_PREFIX.length()), pd.getStreamAccess());
        }
        return pd;
    }

}
```

It is added to `persistence.xml` as in the original answer. It basically removes the prefix in package descriptor name that is causing the exception.
This way, it works and no package scanning needs to be disabled.

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the package containing the JAXB generated classes (that is the package containing the `package-info` class) in an external jar. Move to the new project the JAXB related resources, too (e.g., the XSD file).

Now you can set such a jar as a dependency of the project producing the exacutable jar.

This way, my Spring Batch/Spring Boot project works when I run it from command line. I'm aware that it's not an optimal solution but, in my case, it works.

Comment: When did this become a requirement for JAXB classes to be separated out into separate projects? They can no longer live in the source tree of your code? I mean our JAXB classes are a core part of our spring-boot app itself.... not a separate library.

Comment: Please, ask spring boot guys, not me.