# Spring Boot, ClassNotDef Error with JaxB, Package -Info.java

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jaxb

I am using AJSC framework in SpringBoot with JaxB implementation. I built the stubs outside the project and copied them inside the project with proper directories.

However, during API execution, i get a classNotDef error. But I have seen my Jar file and i have the package-info class file inside the directory.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BOOT-INF/classes/com/att/fpp/fpprome/opportunity/package-info (wrong name: com/att/fpp/fpprome/opportunity/package-info)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.classForName(StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl$4.classForName(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:758)
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.packageForName(JavaReflectionManager.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindPackage(AnnotationBinder.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.prepare(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at acsi.grid.gridcore.core.sql.EntityManagerHelper.getDefaultEntityManager(EntityManagerHelper.java:250)
    at acsi.grid.gridcore.core.sql.EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager(EntityManagerHelper.java:174)
    at acsi.grid.gridcore.core.JdbcGridBagImpl.getEntityManager(JdbcGridBagImpl.java:188)
    at acsi.grid.gridcore.core.JdbcGridBagImpl.put(JdbcGridBagImpl.java:163)
    at com.att.fpp.fpprome.dao.impl.OpportunityDaoImpl.updateOpportunityDatabaseROME(OpportunityDaoImpl.java:497)
    at com.att.fpp.fpprome.bo.impl.OpportunityBusinessObjectImpl.getOpptyInfo(OpportunityBusinessObjectImpl.java:78)
    at com.att.fpp.fpprome.service.impl.OpportunityServiceImpl.getOpportunitiesById(OpportunityServiceImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
```

Also I noticed that I am not using apache.cxf anywhere in pom but yet it is being called here.

Comment: Same problem, with spring-boot 1.5.x, this all worked fine previously. Can anyone at spring assist?

Comment: For anyone else in the spring world, here is a sample project re-producing the issue: https://github.com/nfedyk/spring-boot-jpa-issue-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
The AJSC framework implementing the ADF (Hibernate based ORM) did not support package-info and hence searched for that class everytime.

Only way around was to execute the command to not generate the package-info during stubs generation.

Use `-npa` in **XJC** utility to suppress package-info and everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for the `NoClassDefFoundError` originated by the `package-info` class: [Spring boot, runnable jar can't load package-info.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782191/spring-boot-runnable-jar-cant-load-package-info-class/46169288#46169288)

Answer (score 0):

In case you got here by looking for a solution to a similar "package-info (wrong name:" issue, I fixed my problem by upgrading hibernate (since the one in the app was quite old).